# How to check the Status of Access Transparency Enabled or not on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm working with Google Cloud services, and I want to ensure that Access Transparency is enabled for my project (using Googleclientapi library in Python). Can someone guide me on how to check whether Access Transparency is currently enabled or not for my Google Cloud project? I would appreciate any insights or code examples to help me verify its status programmatically.
Thank you!

I've tried searching for documentation on GCP related to the problem I'm having, but I haven't been able to find a solution.